# How to read CP895 (Kamenicky) encoded DBF file in Java

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, dbf

I have a DBF file encoded in CP895 (Kamenicky) and I want to read it in Java.
How can I reencode CP895 to UTF8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step - create Kamenicky character table:

> public static char[] getKamenickyCharTable() {
>             char[] map = { '\u0000', '\u0001', '\u0002', '\u0003', '\u0004', '\u0005', '\u0006', '\u0007', '\u0008', '\u0009', '\n', '\u000B',
>   '\u000C', '\r', '\u000E', '\u000F',
>                     '\u0010', '\u0011', '\u0012', '\u0013', '\u0014', '\u0015', '\u0016', '\u0017', '\u0018', '\u0019', '\u001A', '\u001B', '\u001C',
>   '\u001D', '\u001E', '\u001F',
>                     '\u0020', '\u0021', '\u0022', '\u0023', '\u0024', '\u0025', '\u0026', '\'', '\u0028', '\u0029', '\u002A', '\u002B', '\u002C',
>   '\u002D', '\u002E', '\u002F',
>                     '\u0030', '\u0031', '\u0032', '\u0033', '\u0034', '\u0035', '\u0036', '\u0037', '\u0038', '\u0039', '\u003A', '\u003B', '\u003C',
>   '\u003D', '\u003E', '\u003F',
>                     '\u0040', '\u0041', '\u0042', '\u0043', '\u0044', '\u0045', '\u0046', '\u0047', '\u0048', '\u0049', '\u004A', '\u004B', '\u004C',
>   '\u004D', '\u004E', '\u004F',
>                     '\u0050', '\u0051', '\u0052', '\u0053', '\u0054', '\u0055', '\u0056', '\u0057', '\u0058', '\u0059', '\u005A', '\u005B', '\',
>   '\u005D', '\u005E', '\u005F',
>                     '\u0060', '\u0061', '\u0062', '\u0063', '\u0064', '\u0065', '\u0066', '\u0067', '\u0068', '\u0069', '\u006A', '\u006B', '\u006C',
>   '\u006D', '\u006E', '\u006F',
>                     '\u0070', '\u0071', '\u0072', '\u0073', '\u0074', '\u0075', '\u0076', '\u0077', '\u0078', '\u0079', '\u007A', '\u007B', '\u007C',
>   '\u007D', '\u007E', '\u007F',
>                     '\u010C', '\u00FC', '\u00E9', '\u010F', '\u00E4', '\u010E', '\u0164', '\u010D', '\u011B', '\u011A', '\u0139', '\u00CD', '\u013E',
>   '\u013A', '\u00C4', '\u00C1',
>                     '\u00C9', '\u017E', '\u017D', '\u00F4', '\u00F6', '\u00D3', '\u016F', '\u00DA', '\u00FD', '\u00D6', '\u00DC', '\u0160', '\u013D',
>   '\u00DD', '\u0158', '\u0165',
>                     '\u00E1', '\u00ED', '\u00F3', '\u00FA', '\u0148', '\u0147', '\u016E', '\u00D4', '\u0161', '\u0159', '\u0155', '\u0154', '\u00BC',
>   '\u00A1', '\u00AB', '\u00BB',
>                     '\u2591', '\u2592', '\u2593', '\u2502', '\u2524', '\u2561', '\u2562', '\u2556', '\u2555', '\u2563', '\u2551', '\u2557', '\u255D',
>   '\u255C', '\u255B', '\u2510',
>                     '\u2514', '\u2534', '\u252C', '\u251C', '\u2500', '\u253C', '\u255E', '\u255F', '\u255A', '\u2554', '\u2569', '\u2566', '\u2560',
>   '\u2550', '\u256C', '\u2567',
>                     '\u2568', '\u2564', '\u2565', '\u2559', '\u2558', '\u2552', '\u2553', '\u256B', '\u256A', '\u2518', '\u250C', '\u2588', '\u2584',
>   '\u258C', '\u2590', '\u2580',
>                     '\u03B1', '\u00DF', '\u0393', '\u03C0', '\u03A3', '\u03C3', '\u00B5', '\u03C4', '\u03A6', '\u0398', '\u03A9', '\u03B4', '\u221E',
>   '\u03C6', '\u03B5', '\u2229',
>                     '\u2261', '\u00B1', '\u2265', '\u2264', '\u2320', '\u2321', '\u00F7', '\u2248', '\u00B0', '\u2219', '\u00B7', '\u221A', '\u207F',
>   '\u00B2', '\u25A0', '\u00A0' };
>             return map;
>         }

Second step - read bytes from DBF and encode chars:

> ```
>                   byte[] bytes = column.getBytes();
>
>                   for (int x = 0; x < bytes.length; x++) {
>                       int index = (0xff) & bytes[x];
>                       char c = getKamenickyCharTable()[index];
>                   }
> ```